# How to access protected base class function, from derived class through base class ptr

Tags: c++, protected, derived-class

I have abstract class A, from which I inherit a number of classes. In the derived classes I am trying to access protected function in A trough A pointer. But I get a compiler error.

```
class A
{
   protected:
        virtual  void f()=0;
};

class D : public A
{
    public:
         D(A* aa) :mAPtr(aa){}
         void g();

    protected:
         virtual void f();

    private:
      A* mAPtr; // ptr shows to some derived class instance
};

void D::f(){  }


void D::g()
{
   mAPtr->f();
}
```

The compiler error says : cannot access protected member A::f declared in class A.

If I declare mAPtr to be D*, instead A* everything compiles. And I don't understand why is this.

Comment: Your testcase is broken. You have a commented `}` and you forgot semicolons after your class definitions. Show us an **actual** testcase please; show us the one you used when you tested/debugged with codepad or ideone. ([\*ahem\*](http://www.ideone.com/OS4zV))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protected data in parent class not available in child class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414506/protected-data-in-parent-class-not-available-in-child-class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relying on `private` access works on unrelated instances of the same type.

Relying on `protected` access works on unrelated instances of the same type (and of more derived types).

However, relying on `protected` access does *not* work on unrelated instances of a base type.

> `[n3290: 11.5/1]:` **When a** friend or a **member function of a derived
>   class references a protected nonstatic member function** or protected
>   nonstatic data member **of a base class**, an access check applies in
>   addition to those described earlier in clause 11. Except when forming
>   a pointer to member (5.3.1), **the access must be through a pointer
>   to, reference to, or object of the derived class itself (or any class
>   derived from that class)** (5.2.5). If the access is to form a pointer
>   to member, the nested-name-specifier shall name the derived class (or
>   any class derived from that class).

So `D` or something derived from `D`, but not `A`.

It's an oft-questioned cute oddity about C++ that nonetheless is designed to try to avoid pitfalls. After all, you don't know what type `*mAPtr` *really* has.

Answer (score 2):

A class containing a protected section means that this class allows derived classes to manipulate their base class in any way they choose (as far as the protected interface allows).

Class D objects can manipulate their own A part. In doing say they probably want to maintain some invariants.

Suppose there is (or will be in the future!) another class E, also inherited from A. Class E objects also can manipulate their own A part, and they may be enforcing different invariants.

Now, if a class D object was allowed to manipulate the A part of any object, it can't ensure the invariants. A D object may do something to the A part of an E object that breaks that E object. That's why it is not allowed.

---

But if you really want to, perhaps a way to call A::f, without exposing it to everybody, would be via a friend function.

```
class A;

namespace detail
{
   void call_f(A*);
}

class A
{
   friend void detail::call_f(A*);
private:
   virtual void f() = 0;
};

namespace detail
{
   void call_f(A* a) { a->f(); }
}

class D: public A
{
public: 
    void g() { detail::call_f(mAPtr); }
private: 
    void f() {}
    A* mAPtr;
};
```

This relies on users being disciplined enough to stay out of namespaces whose name clearly indicates that it contains implementation details.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot using `;` after class declaration:

```
class A
{
   protected:
       virtual  void f()=0;
};

class D : public A
{
    public:
        void g();

    protected:
        void f();

    private:
       A* mAPtr; // ptr shows to some derived class instance
};
```

Besides, you don't need to store base class pointer.

Comment: Besides the typos in the testcase, you missed the problem. And how do _you_ know that he doesn't need to store an `A*`? Why would he be doing it, otherwise?

Comment: This does not answer the question.