# C++ protected: fail to access base's protected member from within derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-control, protected

Admittedly, this question title sounds pretty much exactly the same as the question you neighbour Mike has repeatedly asked. I found quite a few questions worded the same way, but none was what my question is about.

First of all, I'd like to clarify a few points for the context of this question:

1, c++ access control works on a class basis rather than instance basis. Therefore, the following code is completely valid.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int b_;

public:
    bool IsEqual(const Base& another) const
    {
        return another.b_ == b_; // access another instance's protected member
    }
};
```

2, I completely understand why the following code is NOT valid - another can be a sibling instance.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // to correct the problem, change the Base& to Derived&
    bool IsEqual_Another(const Base& another) const
    {
        return another.b_ == b_;
    }
};
```

Now time to unload my real question:

Assume in the Derived class, I have an array of Base instances. So effectively, Derived IS A Base(IS-A relation), and Derived consists of Base(Composite relation). I read from somewhere that this(refers to the design of both IS-A and Has-A) is a design smell and I should never have a scenario like this in the first place. Well, the mathematical concept of  Fractals, for example, can be modelled by both IS-A and Has-A relations. However, let's disregard the opinion on design for a moment and just focus on the technical problem.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    Base base_;

public:
    bool IsEqual_Another(const Derived& another) const
    {
        return another.b_ == b_;
    }

    void TestFunc()
    {
        int b = base_.b_; // fail here
    }
};
```

The error message has already stated the error very clearly, so there's no need to repeat that in your answer:

> Main.cpp:140:7: error: ‘int Base::b_’ is protected
>      int b_;
>          ^
>   Main.cpp:162:22: error: within this context
>       int b = base_.b_;

Really, according to the following 2 facts, the code above should work:

1, C++ access control works on class basis rather than instance basis(therefore, please don't say that I can only access Derived's b_; I can't access a stand alone Base instance's protected members - it's on class basis).

2, Error message says "within this context" - the context is Derived(I was trying to access a Base instance's protected member from within Derived. It's the very feature of a protected member - it should be able to be accessed from within Base or anything that derives from Base.

So why is the compiler giving me this error?

Answer (score 2):

The access rules could in principle have provided an exemption for this special case, where it's known that `Base` is the *most derived class*, the dynamic type of the object. But that would have complicated things. C++ is sufficiently complicated.

A simple workaround is to provide a `static` `protected` accessor function up in `Base`.

A more hack'ish workaround is to use the infamous type system loophole for member pointers. But I'd go for the `static` function, if I had to stick with the basic design. Because I think like there's not much point in saving a few keystrokes when the resulting code is both hard to get right in the first place, and hard to understand for maintainers.

---

Concrete example:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int b_;

    static
    auto b_of( Base& o )
        -> int&
    { return o.b; }

public:
    auto IsEqual( const Base& another ) const
        -> bool
    {
        return another.b_ == b_; // access another instance's protected member
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the special provision for "statically-provable-most-derived-Bases" would also not be desirable because even if the object in question is indeed a `Base`, code *outside* of `Base` is not supposed to muck with its protected members. A `Derived` may play only with *its own* protected base class members because it has authority over them. Any access through other classes needs friend declarations or other provisions *within `Base`'s code*, i.e. `Base` must know about and be aware of it.-- Whether that's in general too restrictive a design guideline is debatable, of course.

Comment: Upvoted for the `static` workaround (even though it's hideous in practice, it's a relatively elegant fix).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Frankly, I don't think C++ should provide that exemption. In fact, I think C++ should forbid the clarification point 1 in my original question. i.e. protected should work on a basis of BOTH class AND instance, rather than JUST class. As pointed out by @PeterA.Schneider and his blog post, I think that level of protection is what "protected" has long intended to achieve and should have achieved. But I'm not here to make the standard, I'm here to understand it. The C++ standard seems to contradicts itself. What do you think?

Comment: @h9uest: Note that you can still *inadvertently* gain access to the protected data, via the member pointer loophole. So the rules are effectively a bit contradictory, not 100% fit with some desired access (regardless of what that desired access would be). So I don't think it's by detailed design, but just for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

> 2, Error message says "within this context" - the context is Derived(I was trying to access a Base instance's protected member from within Derived. It's the very feature of a protected member- it should be able to be accessed from within Base or anything that derives from Base.

Okay, had to go to the standard for this one.

So you're asking, "Why isn't it possible?" The answer: Because of how the standard *really* defines protected member access:

> § 11.4
>   Protected member access
>
> [1]
>   An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11 is applied when a non-static data
>   member or non-static member function is a protected member of its naming class...As described
>   earlier, access to a protected member is granted because **the reference occurs in a friend or member of some class C**.

(emphasis mine)

So let's go over your examples to see what's what.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int b_;

public:
    bool IsEqual(const Base& another) const
    {
        return another.b_ == b_; // access another instance's protected member
    }
};
```

No problem. `another.b_` is `Base::b_`, and we're accessing it from a member function `Base::IsEqual(const Base&) const`.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // to correct the problem, change the Base& to Derived&
    bool IsEqual_Another(const Base& another) const
    {
        return another.b_ == b_;
    }
};
```

Here, we're accessing `Base::b_` again, but our context is a member function `Derived::IsEqual_Another(const Base&) const`, which isn't a member of `Base`. So no go.

Now for the alleged culprit.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    Base bases_[5];

public:
    bool IsEqual_Another(const Derived& another) const
    {
        return another.b_ == b_;
    }

    void TestFunc()
    {
        int b = bases_[0].b_; // fail here
    }
};
```

`bases_[0].b_` is accessing the protected `Base::b_`, inside the context of `Derived::TestFunc()`, which isn't a member (or friend...) of `Base`.

So looks like the compiler is acting in accordance with the rules.

Comment: The OP's explanation of the basic rationale for the general case, "another can be a sibling  [class] instance.", is good. The above is just about how the standard implements that rationale. It does not answer the OP's question, and not even the basic rationale (that the OP provided himself), nor does it provide any solution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  How so? If you're doing, `void Derived::f() { Base b; b.b_; }` there's no way you're accessing siblings, and it's still an error. The rationale is obviously larger than that (even though it surprised me before I checked up on it).

Comment: Yes, that's what the OP's question is about, why it's still an error. Not *how* the rules of the standard make it an error, but *why*.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Right. So "siblings" isn't the general rationale. The explanation here is apparently closer to being "*protected* means less than you thought it did", even though they aren't responsible for our expectations and prejudice. It's just how the language defines it from the get-go. Or are you asking, "What would happen if the language defined it otherwise?"

Comment: Well, siblings are the general rationale. But it's difficult to design rules that are both not unreasonably complex, and a perfect fit. And so the rules for direct access are too protective, so to speak, while the rules for member data pointers are too lenient, in a way; it's as simple as that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't know. What would be complex about defining it like that in the standard, if that's all it were? Anyway, the answer indeed answers the OP's question, because he took this for a fact: "It's the very feature of a protected member - it should be able to be accessed from within Base or anything that derives from Base."

Comment: Re complexity, where do you draw the line wrt. what the compiler can take into account in order to know that `Base` is the most derived class? Trying to design some wording that will ensure all compilers do this identically, will probably convince you that it isn't simple. Re the OP's understanding, note that he wrote about what he understood (including the sibling class problem), and what not; what you quoted is taken out of that context.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But I don't say that the sibling problem is the only rationale, just because I haven't tried formulating a fool-proof definition of it and tested it for years. Since--most likely--neither of us has consulted whoever formulated that rule, we shouldn't speak in their name and say they just took the easy way out. Perhaps there are additional reasons that we're missing in our bubble here. Either way, the OP understood the sibling problem; but he still (understandably, as I did too) overestimated the facts of what *protected* actually means in C++, in its most basic definition.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Thanks for the answer. I inspected that section and its context as well. The bold sentence in your quote was a bit misleading(at least to me). That sentence was just explaining why protected access was granted in a particular example(in that example, it's the non-static member of the naming class C). As a rule, the Base's protected members can be used in Derived class as well as in the naming (Base) class. It's the very definition of "protected".

Comment: @YamMarcovic Also, according to your explanation of the alleged culprit section, I shouldn't be able to access Derived's own b_ in Derived's context(member function in particular), which is obviously contradicting the reality.

Comment: @h9uest `As a rule, the Base's protected members can be used in Derived class` -- based on what? While inspecting the standard, did you find anything that says this without qualifications?

Comment: @h9uest `which is obviously contradicting the reality` No, because `Derived` has inherited `Base`, and now `b_` is its own member. But `Base::b_`, outside the context of `Derived`, isn't.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Base on the very first thing said by Clause 11: A member of a class can be
— private; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.
— protected; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is
declared, by classes derived from that class, and by their friends (see 11.4).

Comment: @h9uest That's why I added "without qualifications". You just left out the `(see 11.4)` at the end of that statement, which adds the qualifications I mentioned. `private` *and* `public`, by the way, have no such qualification in that same paragraph. They're taken as-is.

Comment: @YamMarcovic "No, because Derived has inherited Base, and now b_ is its own member." Even if Derived has b_, Derived is not the naming class of b_; Base is the naming class of that non static b_. The condition for an additional access check is not met, I don't see how the additional access check kicks in. Also, to be clear, what additional access check exactly do you think the standard was referring to? Are you saying, the compiler checks whether the field accessed(bases_[0].b_) is a non-static && protected field of the naming class Base; if yes, grant access; else, do not grant access?

Comment: @h9uest In the paragraph, the 'class C' is defined twice as two separate things in two different scopes. First as "the naming class C", and then "for some [possibly different] class C". In the latter case, `b_` is a member of `Derived`.

Comment: @h9uest The paragraph defines rules pertaining to the case where the member is non-static and protected, aka, a protected instance member. In those case, it applies the aforementioned rules to check if in that context the access it valid.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This discussion goes to show that the OP didn't, in fact, only ask for the rationale. He's doubting whether the compiler is implementing the standard correctly, based on what the standard says (which is what I'm arguing for).

Comment: @YamMarcovic I read chapter 11 numerous times but did not find THE C. I found 3 places where C was declared/defined: a) page 244, 11.3.10, but access was not granted, obviously not THE C. b) page 243, 11.3.3, but there's no access from a base class at all, so not THE C. c) page 238, 11.0.9, this is to illustrate another problem, not THE C. So what C was the standard & you referring to? Also, can you be explicit about the additional check? What is the boolean expression? Feel free to use English or Pseudocode, I'm just interested to know what exactly the standard wants to do.

Comment: @h9uest 11.4 in the 2011 standard (p. 254) uses its own "C" to describe the place in the source where the member in question is used (inside a member or friend function of C). Within 11.4 C is always the same C. All access to non-static members must be through expressions of type C (or derivates). No ancestors, no siblings. 11.4 uses the term "naming class" of the member in question. The term is explained in 11.2/5 as "the class in which the member name was looked up and found", i.e. a static property at compile time. There are lots of examples attached which demonstrate the cases neatly.

Answer (score 2):

I am just turning my comments into an answer because I find the issue interesting. In particular that in the following minimal example `D` doesn't compile baffled me:

```
class B            { protected: int i;          };
class D : public B { int f(B &b){ return b.i; } };
```

After all, a `D` is a `B` and should be able to do all that a `B` can do (except access `B`'s private members), shouldn't it?

Apparently, the language designers of both C++ and C# found that too lenient. Eric Lippert [commented one of his own blog posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/11/09/why-cant-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class/#comment-2844) saying

> But that’s not the kind of protection we’ve chosen as interesting or valuable. "Sibling" classes do *not* get to be friendly with each other because otherwise protection is very little protection.

**EDIT:**
Because there seems to be some confusion about the actual rule laid forth in 11.4 I'll parse it and illustrate the basic idea with a short example.

1. The purpose of the section is laid out, and what it applies to (non-static members).

   > An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11
   >   is applied when a non-static data member or non-static member function
   >   is a protected member of its naming class (11.2)

   The naming class in the example below is `B`.
2. Context is established by summarising the chapter so far (it defined access rules for protected members). Additionally a name for a "class C" is introduced: Our code is supposed to reside inside a member or friend function of C, i.e. has C's access rights.

   > As described earlier, access to a protected member is
   >   granted because
   >   the reference occurs in a friend or member of some 
   >   **class C.**

   "Class C" is also class `C` in the example below.
3. Only now the actual check is defined. The first part deals with pointers to members, which we ignore here. The second part concerns your everyday accessing a member of an object, which logically *"involve a (possibly implicit) **object expression**"*.
   It's just the last sentence which describes the "additional check" this whole section was for:

   > **In this case, the class of the object expression** 
   >   [through which the member is accessed -pas] 
   >   **shall be C or a class derived from C.**

   The "object expression" can be things like a variable, 
   a return value of a function, or a dereferenced pointer. 
   The "class of the object expression" is a compile time 
   property, not a run time property; access through one 
   and the same object may be denied or granted depending 
   on the type of the expression used to access the member.

This code snippet demonstrates that.

```
class B { protected: int b; };

class C: public B 
{
    void f()
    {
        // Ok. The expression of *this is C (C has an
        // inherited member b which is accessible 
        // because it is not declared private in its
        // naming class B).
        this->b = 1;    

        B *pb = this;

        // Not ok -- the compile time 
        // type of the expression *pb is B.
        // It is not "C or a class derived from C"
        // as mandated by 11.4 in the 2011 standard.
        pb->b = 1;
    }
};
```

---

I initially wondered about this rule and assume the following rationale:

The issue at hand is data ownership and authority.

Without code *inside* `B` explicitly providing access (by making `C` a friend or by something like Alf's static accessor) no other classes except those who "own" the data are allowed to access it. This prevents gaining illicit access to the protected members of a class by simply defining a sibling and modifying *objects of the original derived class* through the new and before unknown sibling. Stroustrup speaks of "subtle errors" in this context in the TCPPL.

While it would be safe to access (different) objects of the original base class from a derived class' code, the rule is simply concerned with *expressions* (a compile time property) and not objects (a run time property). While static code analysis may show that an expression of some type `Base` actually never refers to a sibling, this is not even attempted, similar to the rules concerning aliasing. (Maybe that is what Alf meant in his post.)

I imagine the underlying design principle is the following: Guaranteeing ownership and authority over data gives a class the guarantee that it can maintain invariants related to the data ("after changing protected `a` always also change `b`"). Providing the possibility to change a protected property from by a sibling may break the invariant -- a sibling does not know the details of its sibling's implementation choices (which may have been written in a galaxy far, far away). A simple example would be a `Tetragon` base class with protected `width` and `height` data members plus trivial public virtual accessors. Two siblings derive from it, `Parallelogram` and `Square`. `Square`'s accessors are overridden to always also set the other dimension in order to preserve a square's invariant of equally long sides, or they only just use one of the two. Now if a `Parallelogram` could set a `Square`'s `width` or `height` directly through a `Tertragon` reference they would break that invariant.

Comment: Peter, the blog post you shared is totally awesome. Regarding the rationale for data ownership and authority, frankly I completely agree with you. In fact a long time ago, I thought protected should be based on instance AND class - i.e. the clarification point 1 before I unloaded my question should NOT work. However, I had to admit my previous understanding was wrong, because: 1) the clarification point turns out to be correct in practice; 2) according to the very definition of protected in C++ standard, clause 11 on page 237, a protected name can be used by derived classes. What do you think?

Comment: @h9uest I think for things like assignment and other operations involving two instances of a type it is reasonable to be able to manipulate protected members  of other instances.

Comment: Congratulations Peter. The C++ standard committee apparently think the same way. See my own answer below. I check the source code of gcc and compared that with the C++ standard, got the conclusion that the standard still wants the protected member access to be on a class basis, except for the scenarios like assignment, equal, operator overloads, etc, where the protected member can be directly accessed via an instance.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `bases_` being protected in `Derived`, it is all about `b_` being protected in `Base`.

As you have already stated, `Derived` can only access protected members of its base class, not of any other `Base`objects. Not even if they are members of `Derived`.

If you *really* need access, you can make `Derived` a friend on `Base`.

Comment: Hi Bo. Thanks for the quick answer. Here's the confusing part: the clarification point 1 before I unloaded my question is exactly the thing I can't convince myself of. You see, I was accessing the protected member of a totally independent Base instance and the compiler was fine with it.

Comment: I would have failed this as a quiz question. Do you have a rationale for this? After all, Derived is a Base which doesn't seem to make it unreasonable to interact with other Bases on a private basis, so to speak, at least if protected ;-). Because Bases proper *can* do that. Why is it that deriving from Base makes a class -- after all, a Base, among others! -- lose that capability?

Comment: To provide one answer to my own question: Eric Lippert has written about the equivalent rule in C# and simply seems to think that less strict semantics for `protected` would not protect sufficiently (in his comment to his blog, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/11/09/why-cant-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class/#comment-2844). He doesn't elaborate, but I asssume the following: Given a mammal A, user code could change A's protected mammal state "legally" through a dummy sibling mammal B, an "attack" A could not "protect" against -- undesirable to the designers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been bothered by this wicked thing for a night. Endless discussions and the ambiguity of clause 11.4(as quoted by Yam marcovic)

> § 11.4 Protected member access
>
> [1] An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11 is applied when a non-static data member or non-static member function is a protected member of its naming class...As described earlier, access to a protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend or member of some class C.

have burned me out. I decided to resort to the gcc source code(gcc 4.9.2 in my case) to check how those gcc guys understood the clause 11.4, and what check exactly the C++ standards wants to do and how those checks are supposed to be done.

In gcc/cp/search.c:

```
/* Returns nonzero if it is OK to access DECL through an object
indicated by BINFO in the context of DERIVED.  */

static int protected_accessible_p (tree decl, tree derived, tree binfo)
{
  access_kind access;

  /* We're checking this clause from [class.access.base]

   m as a member of N is protected, and the reference occurs in a
   member or friend of class N, or in a member or friend of a
   class P derived from N, where m as a member of P is public, private
   or protected.

Here DERIVED is a possible P, DECL is m and BINFO_TYPE (binfo) is N.  */

  /* If DERIVED isn't derived from N, then it can't be a P.  */
  if (!DERIVED_FROM_P (BINFO_TYPE (binfo), derived))
    return 0;

  access = access_in_type (derived, decl);

  /* If m is inaccessible in DERIVED, then it's not a P.  */
  if (access == ak_none)
    return 0;

  /* [class.protected]

 When a friend or a member function of a derived class references
 a protected nonstatic member of a base class, an access check
 applies in addition to those described earlier in clause
 _class.access_) Except when forming a pointer to member
 (_expr.unary.op_), the access must be through a pointer to,
 reference to, or object of the derived class itself (or any class
 derived from that class) (_expr.ref_).  If the access is to form
 a pointer to member, the nested-name-specifier shall name the
 derived class (or any class derived from that class).  */
  if (DECL_NONSTATIC_MEMBER_P (decl))
  {
  /* We can tell through what the reference is occurring by
 chasing BINFO up to the root.  */
    tree t = binfo;
    while (BINFO_INHERITANCE_CHAIN (t))
    t = BINFO_INHERITANCE_CHAIN (t);

    if (!DERIVED_FROM_P (derived, BINFO_TYPE (t)))
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

The most interesting part is this:

```
  if (DECL_NONSTATIC_MEMBER_P (decl))
  {
  /* We can tell through what the reference is occurring by
 chasing BINFO up to the root.  */
    tree t = binfo;
    while (BINFO_INHERITANCE_CHAIN (t))
    t = BINFO_INHERITANCE_CHAIN (t);

    if (!DERIVED_FROM_P (derived, BINFO_TYPE (t)))
    return 0;
  }
```

1) derived in the code is the context, which in my case is the Derived class;

2) binfo in the code represents the instance whose non-static protected member is access, which in my case is base_, Derived's protected data member Base instance;

3) decl in the code represents base_.b_.

What gcc did when translating my code in question was:

1) check if base_.b_ is non-static protected member? yes of course, so enter the if;

2) climb up the inheritance tree of base_;

3) figure out what actual type base_ is; of course, it's Base

4) check if the result in 3) which is Base, derives from Derived. Of course that's a negative. Then return 0 - access denied.

Apparently, according to gcc's implementation, the "additional check" requested by the C++ standard is the type check of the instance through which the protected member gets accessed. Although the C++ standard did not explicitly mention what check should be done, I think gcc's check is the most sensible and plausible one - it's probably the kind of check the C++ standard wants. And then the question really boils down to the rationale for the standard to request an additional check like this. It effectively makes the standard contradict itself. Getting rid of that interesting section(It seems to me that the C++ standard is asking for inconsistency deliberately), the code should work perfectly. In particular, the sibling problem won't occur as it will be filtered by the statement:

```
if (!DERIVED_FROM_P(BINFO_TYPE(t), derived))
      return 0;
```

Regarding the kind of protection(protected does not work purely on class, but on BOTH class AND instance) mentioned by Peter and the post(by Eric Lippert) he shared, I personally totally agree with that. Unfortunately, by looking at the C++ standard's wording, it doesn't; if we accept that the gcc implementation is an accurate interpretation of the standard, then what the C++ standard really asks for is, a protected member can be accessed by its naming class or anything that derives from the naming class; however, when the protected member is accessed via an object, make sure the owner object's type is the same as the calling context's type. Looks like the standard just wants to make an exception for the clarification point 1 in my original question.

Last but not least, I'd like to thank Yam marcovic for pointing out clause 11.4. You are the man, although your explanation wasn't quite right - the context does not have to be Base, it can be Base or anything derived from Base. The catch was in the type check of the instance through which the non-static protected member was accessed.

Comment: Curiously, your quote on top leaves out the actual additional check 11.4 mandates. Can that be a source of confusion?  What you quote (" access to a protected member is granted because...") is just a repetition of the rules so far ("as described earlier"). The actual additional check is "the class of the object expression [through which the member in question is accessed -pas] shall be C or a class derived from C." C being the class of the location in the source code. No ancestors, no siblings.

Comment: I noticed that @YamMarcovic also didn't quote the important part. I do not think the standard is inconsistent here.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Yes, you're correct. Thanks for pointing out I left out the actual additional check. My bad. However, by making the "arrogant" assertion that the standard is inconsistent, I was referring to the fact that the standard wants to prevent external access to a class's non-static protected member, while it made an exception for the clarification point 1 in my original question. Really, that's the ONLY case where you can possibly access an object's non-static members from an irrelevant external context.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider If you know the rationale for this exception, please share. As you said, "I think for things like assignment and other operations involving two instances of a type it is reasonable to be able to manipulate protected members of other instances.", these use cases can indeed be handy. But I was expecting a reason stronger than that.

Comment: A member function can access even private members of other instances. How else would you implement a copy? Infrastructure functions like assignment and copy are essential; I have a hard time coming up with a stronger reason than that. My gut feeling is still that I would allow access via base expressions as well (i.e. allow even more). But the sibling problem (a sibling may be hiding behind the base expression) seems a great deterrent. I lack the experience to have real-life examples for pitfalls there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of long answers, and quotes from the standard that are correct. I intend on providing a different way of looking at what protected really means that might help understanding.

When a type inherits from a different type, it gets a *base* sub-object. The `protected` keyword means that any derived type can access this particular member within the sub-object that it contains due to the inheritance relationship. The keyword grants access to specific *object*(s), not to *any* object of type base.