# Can't access protected int variable of the pointer Parent class

Tags: c++, variables, protected

I have a question about protected variables. Maybe i didn't really understand them but isnt the reason to use them, that child classes can use them? Overall i want to decrease the lifepoints.

Here is my code:
Header file

```
class Fighter {
protected:
    int offensePoints;
    int defensePoints;
    int lifepoints;
    std::string name;
public:
    Fighter(const std::string n);
    virtual ~Fighter();
    virtual void attackFighter(Fighter * f);
    int randomval(int min, int max);
    bool isalive();
    void isattacked(Fighter * at, int dmg);
};

class Warrior : public Fighter
{
public:
    Warrior(const std::string n);
    virtual ~Warrior();
    void attackFighter(Fighter * f);
    int randomval(int min, int max);
    bool isalive();
    void isattacked(Fighter * at, int dmg);
};
```

Class Fighter:

```
void Fighter::attackFighter(Fighter * f)
{
    if (isalive())
    {
        f->lifepoints -= randomval(0, offensePoints);
    }
}
```

Class Warrior

```
void Warrior::attackFighter(Fighter * f)
{
    if (isalive())
    {
        f->lifepoints -= randomval(0, offensePoints);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: On member Fighter::lifepoints cant be access "through" "Fighter"-pointer (sry for my englisch)

Comment: It most definitely is a duplicate, and there's even a workaround available in the linked dup http://stackoverflow.com/a/1414851/817643

Answer (score -1):

Similar question as in [Protected data in parent class not available in child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414506/protected-data-in-parent-class-not-available-in-child-class)

The solution is to make:

```
void Fighter::Attacked(int offensePoints) {
  if (isalive())
  {
      lifepoints -= randomval(0, offensePoints);
  }
}
```

a **public** function in Fighter, and call that (also removing code duplication).

Comment: Your question you linked is an exact duplicate, flag it as one instead of answering the question.

Comment: this link isnt really helping me at all, but thx

Answer (score -1):

> You can only access protected members in instances of your type (or derived from your type).
>   You cannot access protected members of an instance of a parent or cousin type.
>   In your case, the Derived class can only access the b member of a Derived instance, not of a different Base instance.
>   Changing the constructor to take a Derived instance will also solve the problem.

Found there [Accessing protected members in a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class).

Which means in your case that you can't access to a fighter's lifepoint, but only to a warrior's.

Well this could work but I guess it's not what you are trying to do :

```
void Warrior::attackFighter(Warrior* w)'
```

Another solution is to call fighter's function attackFighter inside warrior's attack

```
void Warrior::attackFighter(Fighter * f)
{
   Fighter::attackFighter(f);
}
```

You could manage to change the behavior of `Fighter::attackFighter`anyway, for example:

```
void Warrior::attackFighter(Fighter * f)
{
   Fighter::attackFighter(f);
   Fighter::attackFighter(f); // This way, a warrior would attack twice when a simple fighter would only attack once.
}
```

This isn't very subtile but I am sure you understood the different possibilities you have to avoid your problem.

Comment: yeah i read that before, how can i solve this?

Comment: @DavidWalser I edited my answer to give you some hints. I didn't run this to see if it works, but it should.